# Ruby 1.9 If I have a shebang pointing to ruby, why doesn't the system see it?

Tags: ruby

I'm using Ubuntu. I'm trying to run a ruby file todo.rb
I added this shebang as the very first line of the file

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

I go to the directory where the rb file is located and then run todo.rb and get error `todo.rb: command not found`.

So I went directly to the /usr/bin directory. I found the env command and ran it. The output of the `env` command displays ruby paths and ruby data:

```
MY_RUBY_HOME=/home/tallercreativo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290
PATH=/home/tallercreativo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/tallercreativo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/home/tallercreativo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/tallercreativo/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
GEM_PATH=/home/tallercreativo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290:/home/tallercreativo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global
RUBY_VERSION=ruby-1.9.2-p290
```

So since, I couldn't make it work, I changed the shebang to point to ruby directly:

```
#!/home/tallercreativo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
```

and I get same command not found error. What's wrong?

Comment: How are you "running" todo.rb and what is the output of `ls -l todo.rb`?

Comment: running: `todo.rb new "Add new field to database for 'accepted terms on date'"` output of `ls -l todo.rb` is `-rw-r--r-- 1 tallercreativo tallercreativo 1232 2012-04-20 11:39 todo.rb`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to first make your script executable:

```
chmod +x todo.rb
```

then you need to run it like so:

```
./todo.rb
```

You cannot run it by just saying `todo.rb`, unless you place it in your `PATH`, in which case you can do so from anywhere.

Comment: aha! ./todo.rb did it! and I also removed the .rb extension so it will look more like a command, so ./todo also works. I'm following the instructions in the Build Awesome Command-Line Applications in Ruby instructions and it doesn't mention the ./ part.

Answer (score 6):

You're missing the `ruby` at the end of your `env` command.  Did you mean:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

You need to tell `env` what executable you're looking for.

### (Question Updated)

Are you executing your code like this?  `todo.rb` ?  You either need to provide the full path to your script (`/home/you/project/todo.rb`) or a relative path (`./todo.rb`) unless that directory is inside your `$PATH`.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to post it. Updated question. Yes, I do have ruby at the end of the env command.

Comment: No worries.  I've updated my answer with some additional ideas.

Comment: If I currently am in the same directory where the todo.rb file is located, do I still need to provide the full path? Can't I just run `todo.rb new "Mown the lawn"`?