# "require" command not found when require 'nokogiri'

Tags: ruby, bash, command-line, nokogiri

Homebrew, ruby 2.0.0p648, nokogiri 1.6.7.2 are installed. When require 'nokogiri' there appears an error:

```
-bash: require: command not found
```

What's wrong?

Comment: How, exactly, are you trying to run the Ruby script? It looks like you're trying to interpret Ruby as a shell script.

Comment: Exactly! I was running require 'nokogiri'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't run a Ruby command directly in bash. If you want to use Ruby at command line, open the Ruby shell **irb**.

```
$ irb
```

and then you'll see the prompt

```
2.3.0 :001 >
```

The first number indicates the Ruby version you are using. In my case it is Ruby 2.3.0. The second number is the command number.

Then you may type

```
require 'nokogiri'
```

and it surely work, if you have this gem installed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, all the necessary gems have been installed. It works

Answer (score 6):

Try running the script from the [console/terminal shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) like this:

```
ruby script_name.rb
```

You can also try adding this [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to the top of your .rb file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

This will auto-identify the script as Ruby when you try to run it directly in some shells.  Also see:

- [Why is it better to use “#!/usr/bin/env NAME” instead of “#!/path/to/NAME” as my shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my)
- [what is the use of “#!/usr/local/bin/ruby -w” at the start of a ruby program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447532/what-is-the-use-of-usr-local-bin-ruby-w-at-the-start-of-a-ruby-program)

Answer (score 0):

You're running your command in bash -- this is a Ruby command.